# how to solve non linear system of equations involving trigonometric functions in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

how to i find the values of b,k1,k3 from the following equations in MATLAB

```
     cos(2*b)- k3 +(2*k1*sin(b))=0
     cos((2*b)+t1-p1)-k3-(k1*(sin(p1-b)-sin(t1+b)))=0
     cos((2*b)+t2-p2)-k3-k1*(sin(p2-b)-sin(t2+b))=0
```

where p1,p2,t1,t2 are known values

Comment: do you have access to the symbolic toolbox?

Comment: No i just know only the basics of MATLAB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the function [fsolve](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html#f477160). It is used to solve system of non linear equations. If you take a look at example 1 in the link I have provided, you could just adapt to your needs.

**Edit**

Based on the values you provided and addressing some of the difficulties, this is how I defined the function (note i fixed the second line of F which had k1 instead of k(1)):

```
function F = func(k)

 t1 = pi/9; 
 t2 = (2*pi)/9; 
 p1 = acot(0.8+cot(t1)); 
 p2 = acot(0.8+cot(t2)); 

 F= [cos(2*k(2))-k(3)+(2*k(1)*sin(k(2))); 
     cos((2*k(2))+t1-p1)-k(3)-(k(1)*(sin(p1-k(2))-sin(t1+k(2)))); 
     cos((2*k(2))+t2-p2)-k(3)-k(1)*(sin(p2-k(2))-sin(t2+k(2)))]; 

end
```

Then to solve it, I called:

```
k0 = [1.523,0.23,3.57]; 
[k fk flag]=fsolve(@func,k0)
Optimization terminated: first-order optimality is less than options.TolFun.

k =

   -0.5210   -1.0933    0.3480


fk =

  1.0e-009 *

    0.2676
    0.2651
    0.2501


flag =

     1
```

Where k is the solution, fk is f(k) which is almost zero (1e-9) and flag =1 means that fsolve converged to a solution, even though the optimization was terminated.

Comment: i tried using fsolve as per the example but it is showing the error as ??? Undefined function or method 'optimoptions' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Error in ==>
options = optimoptions('fsolve','Display','iter');  - @brodroll

Comment: You don't need to get into optimization. Try calling the function in the simplest form: fsolve(@func,x0).

Comment: when i try to run the function,as per the example: function F = myfun1(x)
F = [2*x(1) - x(2) - exp(-x(1));
    -x(1) + 2*x(2) - exp(-x(2))];
end 

it is showing the following error

??? Input argument "x" is undefined.

Error in ==> myfun1 at 2
F = [2*x(1) - x(2) - exp(-x(1));

Comment: Strange, It works for me. How are you calling the function? Which values are you using?

Comment: The only way you would get the error you are saying is by not providing an x value at all, indicating you are after an equation as answer, rather than actual values. The solution I provided was considering what you had written: *where p1,p2,t1,t2 are known values*, which gave me an indication you wanted a numerical solution. Otherwise you should have written that they are *known variables*, and @m.s. was on the right track, for a symbolic solution. For the example: function F = func(x) F = [2*x(1)- x(2)- exp(-x(1));-x(1)+2*x(2)-exp(-x(2))]; end .Calling it: func([0 1]) ans = -2.0000  1.6321.

Comment: i tried for above equations bu it is showing error caused by Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. FSOLVE cannot
    continue.

Comment: I am afraid I won't be able to help you if you can't provide how you are calling any of your functions, which values you are using, or even say if you are after a numerical or analytic/symbolic solution. Consider providing a mwe and not just copying the errors

Comment: function F = fun(k)
t1 = pi/9; t2 = (2*pi)/9;
p1 = acot(0.8+cot(t1)); p2 = acot(0.8+cot(t2));
F= [cos(2*k(2))-k(3)+(2*k(1)*sin(k(2)));
    cos((2*k(2))+t1-p1)-k(3)-(k1*(sin(p1-k(2))-sin(t1+k(2))));
    cos((2*k(2))+t2-p2)-k(3)-k(1)*(sin(p2-k(2))-sin(t2+k(2)))];
end
k0 = [1.523,0.23,3.57];
k= fsolve(@fun,k0)

Comment: This clear things out. I have updated my answer to address some of your issues. Hope it helps. If it does, please consider accepting it as an answer by click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green =)